# Get index of rows which column matches any integer in another list of integers

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataset which draws from another larger dataset.  It is a gene expression dataset, some of the samples in themsaller dataset are of intereste because they are taken from a region of the brain which is part of a particular network of interest.  The unique identifier is called well

```
d = {'network_name': [dDMN, Salience, Salience, Visual, dDNM], 'well_id': [11, 52, 37, 14, 89]}
small_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

bigd = {'Brain_region': [Hp, PFC, dlPFC, V2, Striatum, PFC, V1, Cerebellum], 'well_id': [54, 45, 89, 14, 11, 52, 23, 37]}
big_df = pd.DataFrame(data=bigd)
```

So say I am interested in the Salience network.  I want the index of the well_id which match the list of Well_ids which are labeled as Salience in network_name.  I've found a way to pull the well_id and create a list of well_ids.

```
def pull_well_id (network):
    #takes in the sample annotation datasets as a list of dataframes and the network of interest
    #returns the well ids of all the samples in the list
    well_ids=list(small_df[small_df['network_name']==network]['well_id'])

    return well_ids

IDs=pull_well_id('Salience')
```

Now I want to get the index of the well_ids which match this list in big_df.  I have tried...

```py
ID_index=list(big_df[big_df['well_id']==IDs.index.values)
```

But this does not work at all.  Any suggestions

Comment: Have missing data to reproduce your problem. `IDs`, `sample` and `S1_df` are not defined. Also provide the output you expect from the data

Comment: Sorry about that, I was in a rush to write this and the data-frames I'm actually using are quite large so i could not include them in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `isin`

```
big_df.index[big_df.well_id.isin(IDs)]
```